# Behavior of the intersection between of stable and unstable manifold.

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-points, invariance

Consider a differentiable map $\Psi: M \rightarrow M$ , where $M$ is a differentiable manifold. Let $x^*$ be a hyperbolic fixed point and suppose that the relative stable and unstable manifold intersect transversally in point $x$. Now in view of the invariance of both stable and unstable manifold, I know the image $\Psi(x)$ of $x$ is an intersection point as well.

My question is: why $\Psi(x)$ is the "third" intersection point and not he "second". In other words, why is true the graph of the left side of the image and the graph at right side is wrong? 
There are some qualitative and intuitive proof of this fact?

[image]

P.S. Is it important stay in a two-dimensional manifold?

Answer (score 1):

Both pictures are correct: There is no second or third.

Actually, there are infinitely many such points (those in the orbit of $x$, that is, $\Psi^n(x)$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$), so you can take any of them as "second". In practical terms it means that you can consider any of these images obtained from your own:

[image]

The intersections may come from different orbits, simply because we are considering discrete time and so some complicated behaviors can happen, as in the picture:

[image]

The dynamics is still continuous and so close points go to close points, but this does not forbid such behavior "between" $x$ and $\Psi(x)$.

It goes without saying that it would be immensely difficult, if at all possible, to give explicitly a dynamics exhibiting such a behavior, especially the one in the second picture. Of course, if a point is in the intersection, then all its orbit is also in the intersection.

Exactly the same happens in any dimension assumming that you are considering a transverse intersection.

Comment: Thank you @John B . Maybe I couldn't explain my question very well. I mean ( looking the picture I posted ): given a point of intersection $x$, all other points of intersection are the image $\Psi ^n (x)$ of $x$ ? Or it MUST be happen that the "second" point of intersection ( between $x$ and $\Psi(x)$ )  is not the image of $x$, so it comes from another orbit? It seems this is what my teacher said..

Comment: Both things may happen. I will update my answer noting this, with a drawing.

Comment: Ok, very useful, thank you. But my teacher repeats this fact: the situation in the left side of your picture cannot happen. So I thought that he talks only about preserving-area maps, for example that maps come from Hamiltonian. What do you think about this @John B ? In this case I am agree with "non existence" of situations like your left picture. Is this "preserving-area" hypothesis a typical assumption in a first course of dynamical system? There are other relevant case in which the left side of your picture can't happen?

Comment: I have already replied, so unless I missed the initial question, we are done. Most obviously your teacher needs to give a reference.

Comment: He didn't. However, this means I will post another question